# Delaying CSS3 animations

Tags: css

I have a series of words animating, using css3. A background image of the globe and a styled link follow these words, also animated in css3. My final additions are a more and less button. I want these to follow suit and appear / animate in after or at the same time as the styled link. If anyone could suggest the code to be added to my #more, #less section of css3 would be a big help. 
Thank you, code is below.

```
#more, #less {
    background:none;
    border:none;
    color:#FFF;
    font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    cursor: pointer;

}

.fb-like {
    float:left;
}

h1.main,p.demos {
        -webkit-animation-delay: 18s;
        -moz-animation-delay: 18s;
        -ms-animation-delay: 18s;
    animation-delay: 18s;
}
.sp-container {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 0;
    background: -webkit-radial-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 35%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7));
    background: -moz-radial-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 35%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7));
    background: -ms-radial-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 35%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7));
    background: radial-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 35%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7));
}
.sp-content {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    z-index: 5;
}
.sp-container h2 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    line-height: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin-top: -50px;
    font-size: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    color: transparent;
        -webkit-animation: blurFadeInOut 3s ease-in backwards;
        -moz-animation: blurFadeInOut 3s ease-in backwards;
        -ms-animation: blurFadeInOut 3s ease-in backwards;
    animation: blurFadeInOut 3s ease-in backwards;
}
.sp-container h2.frame-1 {
        -webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
        -moz-animation-delay: 0s;
        -ms-animation-delay: 0s;
    animation-delay: 0s;
}
.sp-container h2.frame-2 {
        -webkit-animation-delay: 3s;
        -moz-animation-delay: 3s;
        -ms-animation-delay: 3s;
    animation-delay: 3s;
}
.sp-container h2.frame-3 {
        -webkit-animation-delay: 6s;
        -moz-animation-delay: 6s;
        -ms-animation-delay: 6s;
    animation-delay: 6s;
}
.sp-container h2.frame-4 {
    font-size: 200px;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 9s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 9s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 9s;
    animation-delay: 9s;
}
.sp-container h2.frame-5 {
        -webkit-animation: none;
        -moz-animation: none;
        -ms-animation: none;
    animation: none;
    color: transparent;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #fff;
}
.sp-container h2.frame-5 span {
        -webkit-animation: blurFadeIn 3s ease-in 12s backwards;
        -moz-animation: blurFadeIn 1s ease-in 12s backwards;
        -ms-animation: blurFadeIn 3s ease-in 12s backwards;
        animation: blurFadeIn 3s ease-in 12s backwards;
    color: transparent;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #fff;
}
.sp-container h2.frame-5 span:nth-child(2) {
        -webkit-animation-delay: 13s;
        -moz-animation-delay: 13s;
        -ms-animation-delay: 13s;
    animation-delay: 13s;
}
.sp-container h2.frame-5 span:nth-child(3) {
        -webkit-animation-delay: 14s;
        -moz-animation-delay: 14s;
        -ms-animation-delay: 14s;
    animation-delay: 14s;
}
.sp-globe {
    position: absolute;
    width: 282px;
    height: 273px;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    margin: -137px 0 0 -141px;
    background: transparent  url(images/globe.png) no-repeat top left;
        -webkit-animation: fadeInBack 3.6s linear 14s backwards;
        -moz-animation: fadeInBack 3.6s linear 14s backwards;
        -ms-animation: fadeInBack 3.6s linear 14s backwards;
    animation: fadeInBack 3.6s linear 14s backwards;
        -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=30)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=30);
    opacity: 0.3;
        -webkit-transform: scale(5);
        -moz-transform: scale(5);
        -o-transform: scale(5);
        -ms-transform: scale(5);
    transform: scale(5);
}
.sp-circle-link {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    bottom: 120px;
    margin-left: -50px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #666;
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight:bolder;
        -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
        -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
        -webkit-animation: fadeInRotate 1s linear 16s backwards;
        -moz-animation: fadeInRotate 1s linear 16s backwards;
        -ms-animation: fadeInRotate 1s linear 16s backwards;
    animation: fadeInRotate 1s linear 16s backwards;
        -webkit-transform: scale(1) rotate(0deg);
        -moz-transform: scale(1) rotate(0deg);
        -o-transform: scale(1) rotate(0deg);
        -ms-transform: scale(1) rotate(0deg);
    transform: scale(1) rotate(0deg);
}
.sp-circle-link:hover {
    background: #333;
    color: #FC0;
    text-shadow:none;
}

#find {
    padding-top:25%;
}

/**/
@-webkit-keyframes blurFadeInOut{
    0%{
        opacity: 0;
        text-shadow: 0px 0px 40px #fff;
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.3);
    }
    20%,75%{
        opacity: 1;
        text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #fff;
        -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    }
    100%{
        opacity: 0;
        text-shadow: 0px 0px 50px #fff;
        -webkit-transform: scale(0);
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes blurFadeIn{
    0%{
        opacity: 0;
        text-shadow: 0px 0px 40px #fff;
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.3);
    }
    50%{
        opacity: 0.5;
        text-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #fff;
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
    }
    100%{
        opacity: 1;
        text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #fff;
        -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadeInBack{
    0%{
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: scale(0);
    }
    50%{
        opacity: 0.4;
        -webkit-transform: scale(2);
    }
    100%{
        opacity: 0.2;
        -webkit-transform: scale(5);
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadeInRotate{
    0%{
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: scale(0) rotate(360deg);
    }
    100%{
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: scale(1) rotate(0deg);
    }
}
/**/
@-moz-keyframes blurFadeInOut{
    0%{
        opacity: 0;
        text-shadow: 0px 0px 40px #fff;
        -moz-transform: scale(1.3);
    }
    20%,75%{
        opacity: 1;
        text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #fff;
        -moz-transform: scale(1);
    }
    100%{
        opacity: 0;
        text-shadow: 0px 0px 50px #fff;
        -moz-transform: scale(0);
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes blurFadeIn{
    0%{
        opacity: 0;
        text-shadow: 0px 0px 40px #fff;
        -moz-transform: scale(1.3);
    }
    100%{
        opacity: 1;
        text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #fff;
        -moz-transform: scale(1);
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes fadeInBack{
    0%{
        opacity: 0;
        -moz-transform: scale(0);
    }
    50%{
        opacity: 0.4;
        -moz-transform: scale(2);
    }
    100%{
        opacity: 0.2;
        -moz-transform: scale(5);
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes fadeInRotate{
    0%{
        opacity: 0;
        -moz-transform: scale(0) rotate(360deg);
    }
    100%{
        opacity: 1;
        -moz-transform: scale(1) rotate(0deg);
    }
}
/**/
@keyframes blurFadeInOut{
    0%{
        opacity: 0;
        text-shadow: 0px 0px 40px #fff;
        transform: scale(1.3);
    }
    20%,75%{
        opacity: 1;
        text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #fff;
        transform: scale(1);
    }
    100%{
        opacity: 0;
        text-shadow: 0px 0px 50px #fff;
        transform: scale(0);
    }
}
@keyframes blurFadeIn{
    0%{
        opacity: 0;
        text-shadow: 0px 0px 40px #fff;
        transform: scale(1.3);
    }
    50%{
        opacity: 0.5;
        text-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #fff;
        transform: scale(1.1);
    }
    100%{
        opacity: 1;
        text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #fff;
        transform: scale(1);
    }
}
@keyframes fadeInBack{
    0%{
        opacity: 0;
        transform: scale(0);
    }
    50%{
        opacity: 0.4;
        transform: scale(2);
    }
    100%{
        opacity: 0.2;
        transform: scale(5);
    }
}
@keyframes fadeInRotate{
    0%{
        opacity: 0;
        transform: scale(0) rotate(360deg);
    }
    100%{
        opacity: 1;
        transform: scale(1) rotate(0deg);
    }
}
```

Comment: Any chance you could put up an example of what you're running now online, might be able to get a better idea of what you're doing.

Comment: its a uni project - http://newmedia.leeds.ac.uk/ug10/cs10mm/abduction.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way I can think of is to count how many seconds in your entire animation that it takes for your styled link to appear and then set a delay for the animation of the more/less buttons, using the [transition-delay property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition-delay) (or if you are using keyframes the [animation-delay property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-delay)). That way, the animation for these won't start until your styled link animates, or they will animate in as the styled link animates in.